# Buying quality electronic devices

Tags: device, buying, certification

As we know there are companies that make cheap and bad stuff and there are others which make good stuff i.e. tested and with warranty. Is there a certified way such as ISO stamps to check for the  quality? What do they tell us about the product?

Comment: Some of my observations: 1. Cheap manufacturers will often put fake certification marks on their products. 2. I don't know of any certification marks that actually test product usability. Most of them are only there to show that in the event of catastrophic failure, the product won't  explode or start a fire or something as drastic as that.

Comment: One of the most important things to remember is that you get what you pay for. If you find a component for half the price it is at major retailers, it's probably a cheap knock-off copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're thinking about ISO-9000 that's about the quality of your organization and its processes, not your products. You can have ISO-9000 certification and still produce the worst crap.

There are certification organizations, like [Underwriters Laboratories](http://www.ul.com) in the US and TüV (Technischer Überwachungsverein) in Germany. Many components won't have certification, though. You'll find it mostly in safety sensitive components, like where isolation from mains is important.
Other organizations, like [IEC](http://www.iec.ch/) (International Electrotechnical Committee) write specifications, but don't certify.

A good manufacturer should hand you its own testing procedures for its components upon request, as well as test reports. Those are sometimes included in datasheets.
Some will refer to certification organization standards, like shown in this snapshot of a [random Littelfuse datasheet](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/Data_Sheets/Littelfuse_Fuse_208.pdf):

[image]

Note that the Underwiters Laboratories (the top logo) and PSE (Product Safety Engineering) logos refer to their respective certification, while the CE logo doesn't imply this. (The CE logo means that you *claim* to comply with CE standards).

Comment: I'm seeing ISO 9001 on the label of product, is that any different?

Comment: @user103241 - they're related. See [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_9000_essentials)

Comment: Sadly, the cheap Chinese copies of many components tend to have convincing stamps and packaging. If you're looking to ensure that you get quality originals, pay the premiums an purchase from a major retailer (e.g. RS Electronics / Farnell) and avoid the smaller companies. Needless to say, you should also avoid places like eBay.

Comment: @Polynomial: Farnell has a Multicomp brand, a pick-and-mix of all kinds of articles for low prices. Specs change frequently, or parts are no longer included in next year's catalog. I always had the impression Multicomp is a brand for cheap Chinese stuff which otherwise would be brandless.

Comment: @FedericoRusso Yeah, that's a good point. It's not just bad retailers, it's bad manufacturers too. Be wary!